# edgeworth box can't draw node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I would like to draw in a caption on the top, bottom, left and right of this graph. Unfortunately I can't seem to draw anything at all:

MWE:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    domain=0:1,
    axis on top,xmin=0]

\addplot[pattern=crosshatch,
    pattern color=red!30!white,
    draw=red!30!white]
    {x^e} \closedcycle;
        \node[anchor=north west] at (-.5,-1.5) {$\iota$};
  \end{axis}  
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=top,
    axis y line=right,
    domain=0:1,
    x dir = reverse,
    y dir = reverse,
    axis on top,xmin=0]
      \addplot[pattern=crosshatch,
    pattern color=blue!30!white,
    draw=blue!30!white]
    {x^e} \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misinterpreting the question but this adds something left, right and so on of the axis.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    domain=0:1,
    axis on top,xmin=0]

\addplot[pattern=crosshatch,
    pattern color=red!30!white,
    draw=red!30!white]
    {x^e} \closedcycle;
        \node[anchor=north west] at (-.5,-1.5) {$\iota$};
  \end{axis}  
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=top,
    axis y line=right,
    domain=0:1,
    x dir = reverse,
    y dir = reverse,
    axis on top,xmin=0]
      \addplot[pattern=crosshatch,
    pattern color=blue!30!white,
    draw=blue!30!white]
    {x^e} \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
    \node[right=1em of current axis]{something right};
    \node[left=1em of current axis]{something left};
    \node[above=1em of current axis]{something above};
    \node[below=1em of current axis]{something below};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]